# Календарь в Java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Data {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test();
    }

    public static void test()
    {
        Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    }
}
```

Почему выводит номер месяца "7" ? Если должно быть "8"

Comment: Запомни, что в программировании очень часто начинается нумерация с 0, а не 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что `7` - это значение константы [`AUGUST`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.AUGUST). Нумерация идет с нуля ([`JANUARY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.JANUARY) - 0)

Comment: Я так и подумал. Но число месяца выводится верно, год тоже, а что же месяц так?

Comment: Возможно, Вам будет полезен этот вопрос: [Why is January month 0 in Java Calendar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar). Некоторые утверждают, что это из-за C API, где месяц начинался с нуля. Другие - что года/дни имеют числовой формат, а месяцы - преимущественно строковый.